# Lazy loading doesn't work - jpa

Tags: jpa, select, lazy-loading, distinct, fetch

Hy all,
  I have three tables Child, Pet and Toy. Pet has a reference key the child id, and a toy has a reference key to a dog id.
  I want to load all data about a Child and his pets, but i don't want to load the toy data

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "petEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<PetEntity> getPetEntitySet() {
    return petEntitySet;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ChildId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public ChildEntity getChildEntity() {
    return childEntity;
}
```

same for set of toys.

to load data i have

```
List<ChildEntity> list = entityManager.createQuery(
"SELECT c FROM ChildEntity c "+
"LEFT JOIN FETCH c.petEntitySet ",
 ChildEntity.class).getResultList();
    return list;
```

but this thing loads me all data, not just the information about child and his pets.

How can i suppress the entity manager to load only the data in the table, and not to make joins when i don't want that

Thanks for your advices

i forgot to mention that in this chase it doesn't only load all data, but it returns more than just one copy of a child elemnt

Comment: Why do you think it loads all data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is loading more data is because you are using the keyword `fetch`. This will `EAGERLY` load whatever the child's pets. 
Just remove the `fetch` and lazy loading will occur.

**Update**

I see that this is actually what you want, so just ensure `equals()` and `hashCode()` is correctly overriden in all relevant classes, as I assume you are using `Set`.

In this way, jpa knows how to look for duplicates

**Second update**

Yes you can easily use `DISTINCT` in your queries.

Just add `DISTINCT` in your select

```
List<ChildEntity> list = entityManager.createQuery(
"SELECT DISTINCT c FROM ChildEntity c "+
"LEFT JOIN FETCH c.petEntitySet ",
 ChildEntity.class).getResultList();
    return list;
```

Comment: i solve that, i have another problem now, if a child has more than 1 pet for eg 3 in the result list i'll have 3 children each with a pet, and not a c achild with tree pests (i am usisng sets), it's there any way in wich i can use something like distinct root, from criteria ?

Comment: what was the exact solution for this problem, i am having similar issues. Did you remove the 'fetch' keyword from the query or from the annotations in your entities?

Comment: Which problem? If it is loading more data, then remove fetch and add distinct

Comment: The original problem the OP asked where when a query is called on a certain entity it traverses and loads all other data in the join when you didn't ask for it?

Comment: Yes. Just ensure equals and hashcode is overriden, remove fetch and use distinct. Should be all you need

Comment: How can i override equals and hashcode, do i do this where i create the query or inside the entity decleration class? And what exactly is overridden or is it just placing @Override on each method?

Comment: Using @Override will tell the compiler to check if you have correctly overriden the method. Override means that you are writing the method the way you want, instead in the Object class (which all java classes inherit from). You must override it in the type of the collection, most probably your entities.

Comment: If removing FETCH is part of the answer, why is that word still present in the query provided for an answer?

Comment: Because it is what he wanted

Comment: Thanks @ShervinAsgari adding `equals` and `hashcode` method helped.  
Then I changed the `toString()` method to remove reference of one of the objects in another object; which was giving `stackoverflowException`